# How to find the intersection of triangle and the curves in 2D?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a triangle ad two lines. I would like to plot the parts of lines inside the triangle with other style. How to find the intersection, please? Many thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

a1 = 1080
a2 = 350
c1 = -7
c2 = 0
d = 7
x = np.linspace(0,100,500)

y1 = a1/(x-c1)-d
y2 = a2/(x-c2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 3]
 
I1 = 23
x_end = 70
plt.xlim(0,x_end)
plt.ylim(0,50)

# Plot curves
plt.plot(x[10:], y1[10:], c = 'red')
plt.plot(x[10:], y2[10:], c = 'blue')

# Plot triangle
shift = 15
triangle = np.array([[0,I1], [x_end,I1+shift], [x_end, I1-shift]])

plt.scatter(triangle[:, 0], triangle[:, 1], s = 0, color = 'grey')

t1 = plt.Polygon(triangle[:3,:])
plt.gca().add_patch(t1)

x = symbols('x')
intercept = solve(a1/(x-c1)-d, (322+3*x)/14) 
print(intercept)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The equations for sides of the triangle are `14y - 3x = 322` and `14y + 3x = 322` and you already have equations of lines. So just solve these to get intersections.

Comment: I added to the code with solve. The solution is []. Why, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fill_between` and set the triangle as clip_path. The zorder needs to be changed to show the green area on top of the triangle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a1 = 1080
a2 = 350
c1 = -7
c2 = 0
d = 7
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 500)

y1 = a1 / (x - c1) - d
y2 = a2 / (x - c2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 3))

I1 = 23
x_end = 70
plt.xlim(0, x_end)
plt.ylim(0, 50)

# Plot curves
ax.plot(x[10:], y1[10:], c='red')
ax.plot(x[10:], y2[10:], c='blue')

# Plot triangle
shift = 15
triangle = np.array([[0, I1], [x_end, I1 + shift], [x_end, I1 - shift]])
ax.scatter(triangle[:, 0], triangle[:, 1], s=1, color='grey')

t1 = plt.Polygon(triangle[:3, :])
ax.add_patch(t1)

ax.fill_between(x[10:], y1[10:], y2[10:], facecolor='lime', clip_path=t1, zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Note that your formula `y2 = a2 / (x - c2)` divides by zero for the first value (0) of x. You might want to start x with a larger value, e.g. `x = np.linspace(0.1, 100, 500)`.

If you don't want to show the triangle, `ax.add_patch()` is still needed for the clipping to work as expected. You could make it invisible (`t1 = plt.Polygon(triangle[:3, :], color='none')` or `t1 = plt.Polygon(triangle[:3, :], visible=False)`).

As commented by @swatchai, if you just want a different line style, you could clip the plotted curves:

```py
t1 = plt.Polygon(triangle[:3, :], visible=False)
ax.add_patch(t1)

#ax.fill_between(x[10:], y1[10:], y2[10:], facecolor='lime', clip_path=t1, zorder=2)
ax.plot(x[10:], y1[10:], 'w:', clip_path=t1)
ax.plot(x[10:], y2[10:], 'w:', clip_path=t1)
```

[image: plot with changed line style]

Comment: The OP wants to plot the parts of lines inside the triangle with other style. So I guess, some code like `ax.plot(x[10:], y1[10:], 'k--', clip_path=t1)`, and `ax.plot(x[10:], y2[10:], 'r--', clip_path=t1)` are also needed.

Comment: Thank you very much